# How do I use event listeners in IE-8 and earlier

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I would like a function which checks if a user has entered enough characters into a form. My code works in chrome but not in IE.

```
var elUsername = document.getElementById('username');  
var elMsg      = document.getElementById('feedback');   

function checkUsername(minLength) {                     
  if (elUsername.value.length < minLength) {           

    elMsg.innerHTML = 'Username must be ' + minLength + ' characters or more';
  } else {                                             
    elMsg.innerHTML = '';                            
  }
}

elUsername.addEventListener('blur', function() {      
  checkUsername(5);                                     
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE5-8 has a different event model and does not support addEventListener() but you can provide fallback code.

```
var elUsername = document.getElementById('username'); 
var elMsg = document.getElementById('feedback');       

function checkUsername(minLength) {                  
  if (elUsername.value.length < minLength) {           

    elMsg.innerHTML = 'Username must be ' + minLength + ' characters or more';
  } else {                                           
    elMsg.innerHTML = '';                              
  }
}

if (elUsername.addEventListener) {             
  elUsername.addEventListener('blur', function(){
    checkUsername(5);                            
  }, false);                                     
} else {                                         
  elUsername.attachEvent('onblur', function(){   
    checkUsername(5);                            
  });
}
```